# Read only fields/slot in R S4 Objects

Tags: r, object, readonly, r-s4

I'm interested in creating an S4 object (or S3) that has read only data, that is the user could not directly modify the values, but could only read them.  Any ideas?
thanks
Mark

Comment: S4 does not support attribute encapsulation AFAIK so there is no simple way to do that. As work-around I could imagine creating an environment as attribute and adding your values as hidden objects (variable names prefixed with a dot) but the user of your S4 class could still so clever to recognize this ;-)